# In NUnit [TearDown], how to find out whether the test was run solo?

Tags: testing, nunit

So, in [TearDown](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TearDown-Attribute), I have got the [info about the test outcome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473201/nunit-is-it-possible-to-check-in-the-teardown-whether-the-test-succeeded) and the test result message, but I would like to handle things specifically on whether the test was run solo (a single test in the test session) or was started in a whole set of tests (e.g. "Run all tests/All tests from Solution").

The goal is to detect, whether the developer individually started the test (manually, from within Visual Studio) or it was started using a Continuous Integration system.

This is what I have so far:

```
/// <summary>
///     A helper function for resolving problems when string comparison fails.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
///     Intended to be used to analyze the detected differences.
/// </remarks>
[TearDown]
public void CompareNonMatchingStringsOnFailure() {
    if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status == TestStatus.Failed) {
        string outputMessage = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message;
        if (outputMessage.StartsWith("Expected string to be ")) {

            // do extended comparison
            // This should only run on single runs, which were initiated manually from visual studio
            //...  
        }
    }
}
```

**How to get info about the test run/session in the TearDown method?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in the code of a teardown because (1) TearDown is still part of a test and (2) tests are not supposed to know anything about who ran them, why they are running etc. The execution environment knows about the test, but the test does not know the execution environment. In fact, NUnit goes to a lot of trouble to make sure things work the same in each environment. While there are ways to trick NUnit, they are generally bad ideas and version-dependent.

Here's what you **can** do...

1. Create a fixture that inherits from your fixture.
2. Put the logic you want in the new fixture TearDown method.
3. Mark the new fixture as `[Explicit]`.
4. Do **not** add any categories to the new fixture.

Because of (3) the new fixture will **not** run as part of CI or even from the IDE when you run all tests.

It can only be run explicitly. Since it has no categories, that means it can only be run by name... i.e. by selecting the entire fixture or a single test.

That isn't **quite** what you asked for. If you run the entire fixture, you will get the full comparison for all the inherited test methods. However, it may be sufficient for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Great idea. Heck, I even tried to add the [Explicit] attribute to the [TearDown] method, as a test. But that did not work :-/